# crude Runtime.exec to call java -cp not working in linux

Tags: java, cross-platform, runtime.exec

I'm using a java process to spawn many other java processes using `Runtime.exec(cmd)` where cmd is like the following:

`java -cp "MyJar.jar" pkg.MyClass some-more-arguments`

running the same command from the command line works fine in windows and linux, however when my spawning java process calls the command via `Runtime.exec` it works in windows **but not in linux.**

in linux i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pkg/MyClass`

any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the PATH and CLASSPATH variables?

Comment: what do you mean? the command should set the classpath via -cp

Comment: what are some-more-arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Runtime.exec(String[]), not Runtime.exec(String)

Answer (score 2):

This snippet of code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo \"hello\"");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

gives this output in linux:

```
"hello"
```

*with* quotes (").

So my suggestion is to remove the quotes (") from the exec-line. They are not removed when the command is executed, but passed to the external program as arguments. It's actually equivalent to writing `java -cp \"MyJar.jar\" ...` in the prompt.

If you *need* the "-marks (MyJar.jar perhaps has spaces or something), I suggest you look at `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp)`. That should even make it more platform-independent.

Comment: Good catch, I wouldn't be surprised if this is the problem!

Comment: thanks, that seems to get me one step further in that it's finding the class, but then i'm faced with another problem, please see edit for more info^